# How to keep track of dependencies with immutable design?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability

What is the way to design software in functional way, when there are dependencies between objects?

```
class Link(val name: String, val links: Vector[Link] = Vector()){

    def changeName(newName: String): Link = {
        new Link(newName, links)
    }

    def connect(other: Link): Link = {
        new Link(name, links :+ other)
    }
}

object Main
{
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
            val A = new Link("A")
            val B = new Link("B")
            val Alinked = A connect B 
            val updatedB = B changeName "B2"
            println(Alinked.links.contains(updatedB))
    }
}
```

Output

> false

I connect A and B, but then B is being changed. It implies, that I have to reconnect new object to previous. In complex hierarchies it can get really hard to control such updates.

How to make automatical relinking? Delegates? Actors?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep the identity of immutable copies of objects together, I think one solution is to introduce a unique identifier:

```
case class Link(id: Int)(val name: String, val links: Vector[Link] = Vector()) {
  def changeName(newName: String): Link =
    new Link(id)(newName, links)

  def connect(other: Link): Link =
    new Link(id)(name, links :+ other)
}

def test(): Boolean = {
  val A         = Link(0)("A")
  val B         = Link(1)("B")
  val Alinked   = A connect B 
  val updatedB  = B changeName "B2"
  Alinked.links.contains(updatedB)
}

assert(test())
```

That is, once an object is created, you carry the same `id` across all copies. The `case class` here makes sure that `equals` is correctly defined by looking at the `id` field.

Comment: So basically there's no way around reinventing pointers and keeping the current state in a `Map[Id, Any]`?

Comment: Well, you could use bi-directional links, then `connect` would have to update both sink and source. But yes, you need a copy of state for each step. If you want a simpler approach that is not mutable but concurrency safe, I recommend using STM (software transactional memory). There is a very good library for Scala

Comment: @0__ Is there a way to have static pointer which always points to last entity of a class?

Comment: @CronAcronis No, because then you are basically back to mutable design, only more complicated. I think bi-directional graphs and mutual dependencies are inherently difficult to maintain in an immutable manner. If your code never runs concurrently, you might as well just use mutable structure. As I said, also have a look at STM. There is also [scala-graph](http://www.scala-graph.org/)